# Handle the ^ and ê key press with JavaFX

Tags: javafx

From a JavaFX application, I would like to be able to type letters like `ê`, `ô`, etc. Using linux and my keyboard mapping, it's done with dead chars (ie. typing `^`, then `e`).

I also tried to handle the `^` key directly. According to the Javadoc, the key code for `^` is [KeyCode.CIRCUMFLEX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#CIRCUMFLEX).

Here is a simple key press test application, which print the name (`e.getCode().getName()`) and and the text (`e.getText()`) of a key each time a key is pressed:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Label label = new Label("Type some text...");
        pane.setLeft(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 40);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> label.setText("name: " + e.getCode().getName() + "\ntext: " + e.getText()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run this application:

- I can't display character requiring dead letters (like `ê`);
- The code for the key `^` is `UNDEFINED`, so I can't handle this key with something like `if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.CIRCUMFLEX)`.

I am wrongly using key events or is it a JavaFX issue? I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Java8.

Edit: A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does your keyboard has the `^` as key ? Cause for example the keyboard i have has it as a combination of `Shift Key` + `6`. That's how i detect it.

Comment: Yes my keyboard have `^`, no `Shift` required.

Comment: Give a try the code to see if it works ;)

Comment: Should be `KeyCode.DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX`...

Comment: Yes, but when I hit `^`, I get : `Name: Undefined text:` (nothing for *text*)

Answer (score 0):

One line with [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html)(using `KeyTyped Event`)

[Works both for the keyboard i use which needs **Shift+6** to print `^`]:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED,
event -> label.setText("name: " + event.getCharacter() + "\ntext: " + event.getCharacter()));
```

---

So to detect if `^` is typed you can use inside the event:

```
if(event.getCharacter().equals("^"){

..... 

}
```

Comment: Nope, getCharacter() retuns an empty string. I also tried this code: `scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> label.setText(
                "code: " + e.getCode() +
                "\nchar: " + e.getCharacter() +
                "\ntext: " + e.getText() +
                "\neventType: " + e.getEventType().getName()));
    }`, nothing is displayed when I hit `^`. This is officially a javaFX issue.

Comment: @roipoussiere `e.getCode()` wouldn't display something  , but `getText()`  can't return `Undefined text` you are typing a character ... it should work.. Strange .... Have you tried Fabians comment? `KeyCode.DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX` Can i have a screenshot of the window when you are using the code?

Comment: I added a screenshot in the original topic.

Comment: @roipoussiere You have added `KeyEvent.ANY` ( It records all the 3 key events so you actually on the window label  take only the last which is KEY_RELEASED)[ Add a `println();` to see what i mean] Try with `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` . Let me know if Fabian's comment works on your computer.

Comment: @roipoussiere What model of keyboard is that which has `^` alone?

Comment: French AZERTY keyboard: http://ibt.ca/v2/items/btc5121w/images/azerty_1.jpg (between `P` and `$`)